# AWS S3api put-object: unknown options (checksum-crc32)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, crc32

So I want to upload a file and have AWS perform a specified CRC32 (let's say the CRC is ABCD1234) check after the upload, but i keep getting this error.

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...]
> [parameters] To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help   aws  help   aws   help
>
> Unknown options: --checksumcrc32, ABCD1234

The command I use goes as follows (brackets [] for variables)

> aws s3api put-object --bucket [BUCKET_NAME] --checksum-crc32
> "ABCD1234" --key [NAME_OF_FILE] --body [DESTINATION_PATH] --profile
> [PROFILE_NAME]

Uploads without the --checksum-crc32 work just fine.

Version: aws-cli/2.4.4

Any guesses why I get this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html?highlight=put) says that the CRC needs to be Base-64 encoded, not hexadecimal:

> --checksum-crc32 (string)
>
> This header can be used as a data integrity check to verify that the
> data received is the same data that was originally sent. This header
> specifies the base64-encoded, 32-bit CRC32 checksum of the object. For
> more information, see Checking object integrity in the Amazon S3 User
> Guide .

So your `ABCD1234` would need to be either `q80SNA==` or `NBLNqw==`, depending on whether they expect the 32 bits to be rendered in big-endian or little-endian order, respectively. I didn't see anything in the documentation that says which it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the "Unknown options" output is not related to the string format, but rather to the missing "x-amz-checksum" header that the docs talk about. However, i don't know how to make a s3api request through aws cli with additional headers :/

Answer (score 1):

The CRC32 doesn't match their calculation. Make sure you're encoding it properly.

You don't need to specify the checksum on the cli, you can have the client calculate it by removing `--checksum-crc32` and replacing it with `--checksum-algorithm "crc32"`

If your goal is data integrity, consider a cryptographically secure algorithm like SHA256, which can also be automatically calculated by the cli.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but using --checksum-algorithm also returns an "Unknown options" error. Plus [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html?highlight=--checksum-algorithm) claim I would need to send a header (x-amz-checksum) with the request. But, is that something supported by the CLI? I have been searching around and I can't find any conclusive answer :(

Comment: The CLI adds the needed headers.
`# aws s3api put-object --bucket ******* --checksum-algorithm "crc32" --key foo.bar --body ./yarn.lock

{
    "ETag": "\"e3b225337370f5b5bd7166add210977b\"",
    "ChecksumCRC32": "v3dO8g=="
}`

Comment: Not sure if I follow. Is yarn.lock the file you are uploading as foo.bar in the s3 bucket? I followed your command structure, but I get another error when i include the items within the curly brackets. (Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.)

I also single-quoted them ('{"ETag":"asdasas"...}') and then they get flagged as unknown options, just like the other flags :(